# MVC does not render view if querystring is used

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.7.2

I have an ASP.NET MVC website. The issue I am having is if I add a querystring, it can't render the view

My controller is

```
public class UpgradeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        return View(id);
    }
}
```

Simple as that

If I navigate to

```
localhost:123456/upgrade/index
```

Then the `view` is rendered in the browser as expected.

As you can see in the `controller`, the `view` `Index` takes a string parameter called `id`.

This should mean the following URL will return the same view

```
localhost:123456/upgrade/index/abc
```

Sadly, it does not render the expected `view`. Instead I see

> The view 'abc' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

The same is true with the following URL

```
http://localhost:53081/upgrade/index?id=abc
```

I have only 1 route

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I am totally baffled as to why it's trying to render a view and treating it like a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the id arg from this line

```
    return View(id)
```

and pass it to the view (if you even need it there) using a different method. see https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/various-ways-to-pass-data-from-controller-to-view-in-mvc/

passing a string value to View method is obviously done with different intentions: without it, the name of the view file is implied from the name of the action method, while with that you have flexibility to load any view that you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I actually did

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    return View(model:id);
}
```